# How can I install Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider without composer?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am on a cpanel shared hosting and don't have access to SSH. How can I install Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider without SSH? 
If I had SSH access I would use:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

But I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Ditch shared hosting, ditch cPanel, and join the 21st century! We have cookies (and SSH access!). :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be downloading it locally with composer and uploading the entire project (including the `vendor` folder) with a ftp client.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Go to https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html and download the repo.

**Step 2**

Copy the zip and navigate to your project. Inside the vendor folder create folder `laravelcollective` and then inside `html`. Inside the `html` folder place the repo.

**Step 3**

On your `composer.json` file on the root directory of your project add the following lines.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "Collective\\Html\\": "vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/"
    },
}
```

and then do

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**Step 4**

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of `config/app.php:`

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks Saravanan. I appreciated the time but again you mentioned: composer dump-autoload which as I said I don't have access to command line.