# How to create method/command to dump-autoload in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I tried this command

```
Route::get('/updateapp', function()
{
    \Artisan::call('dump-autoload');
    echo 'dump-autoload complete';
});
```

and the page display this error:

```
The command "dump-autoload" does not exist.
```

I can't use exec() system() so I need to create this method/command.

I reviewed other questions but I'm confused help me please! I'm newbie

Comment: `dump-autoload` is a `composer` command, and is not callable like this. `\Artisan::call()` executes `php artisan xxx`, where `xxx` is the `protected $signature` of a command that exists in the Laravel framework, or that you have manually created and registered in `App\Console`. Do you not have access to a command line interface where you can manually call `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Also, in a lot of situations, `composer dump-autoload` requires admin/root permissions, so calling that from a URL would try to execute as `webuser` (or similar), which is unlikely to have the correct permissions.

Comment: I tested this in my own hosting and the server is shared (Shared IP Address
) so I can't execute system commands but I can modified the files . I developed the system in local and now I want to upload in my hosting.

Comment: I used LaravelCollective/html I need to add this , but i need to dump-autoload

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043484/how-can-i-install-collective-html-htmlserviceprovider-without-composer but I need to execute composer dump-autoload

Answer (score -1):

```
    \Artisan::call('dump-autoload');
```

This command called above command

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

You must use from command 
And write in anywhere from php script

```
exec('composer dump-autoload');
```

Comment: I tried this but display this error "exec() has been disabled for security reasons"

Comment: Try system() func ?